# Javafx - Determine position of cursor on right click relative to gridpane

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, tile, gridpane

I have a 40x40 gridpane, displaying a map. Currently, i have the following methods listening for a right click:

```
    //detect right click + display menu, select if you want to place item 1 or item 2
    final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    cm.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) 
                event.consume();

        }
    });
    cm.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Following item selected: "+
                    ((MenuItem)event.getTarget()).getText());
        }
    });
    //two placeable items
    MenuItem item1Place = new MenuItem("Item 1");
    MenuItem item2Place = new MenuItem("Item 2");
    cm.getItems().addAll(item1Place, item2Place);

    primaryStage.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) 
            {
              cm.show(primaryStage, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
            } 
        }
    });
```

What I'd like to implement is the following:

> If a menu item is selected after a right click, i'd like to save
>   the position of the right click in a variable  
> e.g. [32,12] if
>   right click was 32 blocks of the gridpane across, and 12 blocks up.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this? 

Thanks in advance

```
// first edit code entered below. I realise the indentation is very off however fixing it seemed to turn it back to plain text
placeItem1.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println("Item 1 placed ["+col+", "+row+"]"));
                placeItem2.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println(Item 2 placed["+col+", "+row+"]"));
                menu.show(cell, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
            });
            root.add(cell, x, y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener to each cell in the grid, instead of adding one mouse listener to the stage. The proper listener to use for context menu handling is a `contextMenuRequested` handler:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClicksInGridPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();

        final int NUM_ROWS = 40 ;
        final int NUM_COLS = 40 ;

        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Item 1");
        MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("Item 2");
        menu.getItems().addAll(menuItem1, menuItem2);

        for (int x = 0 ; x < NUM_COLS ; x++) {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < NUM_ROWS ; y++) {
                Pane cell = new Pane();
                cell.setPrefSize(20, 20);
                // add style just to draw grid:
                cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, white; -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 1;");

                // context menu listener:
                final int col = x ;
                final int row = y ;

                cell.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> {
                    menuItem1.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println("Item 1 selected in cell ["+col+", "+row+"]"));
                    menuItem2.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println("Item 2 selected in cell ["+col+", "+row+"]"));
                    menu.show(cell, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                });

                root.add(cell, x, y);
            }
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i made some progress, however there's one issue. I have a gridpane (produced with scenebuilder) and a for loop to generate it already. The issue is, with the code i added above as an edit (in my main question) the coordinates obtained are wrong (always 39,39). The main (stage is called primaryStage, and the gridPane is named root). Any suggestions as to how i'd go about resolving this?

Comment: @JK96 there's no possible way to tell what you did wrong from the code snippet you posted. Does my example work for you? If so, what are you doing differently? How and where are you defining `col` and `row` in your code?

Comment: the following works for me: menu pops up. right click is detected, selection of item is detected. col and row are defined within a loop exactly the same as the one you posted, however the values obtained for the position seems to be wrong, and is constantly [39,39]

Comment: And they're declared there too, right? You didn't make them instance variables or anything?

Comment: No worries, i solved the issue, thanks for your help! Marked your reply as the correct answer.