# JavaFX - get index row and index col by OnClick on GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, onclick, imageview, gridpane

I need to get the index of my specified click over my GridPane called myGrid. If I put a piece on board from my coord like here below, it works..
for example:
`myGrid.add(new ImageView("othello/images/white.png"), 4, 3);`

If I want to take the position of my click on board I use this method without success..

```
@FXML
   private void clickGrid(MouseEvent event) {
      Node source = (Node)event.getSource() ;
      Integer colIndex = GridPane.getColumnIndex(source);
      Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(source);
      if (colIndex != null && rowIndex != null){
         myGrid.add(new ImageView("othello/images/black.png"), colIndex.intValue(), rowIndex.intValue());
      }     
   }
```

If I don't use

```
if (colIndex != null && rowIndex != null)
```

the error is "Java.NullPointException"

However if I use that in the program, Nothing happens when I try to get the row/col values.
Help? Thank you

EDIT: here my FXML

[image]

Comment: The source of the event is the node with which the handler is registered. Which node(s) is the handler applied to in the FXML file?

Comment: clickGrid is in "On Action" of my GridPane, in FXML. If I click my GridPane he should give me the right row, col index.

Comment: No, because `GridPane.getColumnIndex(node)` gives you the column index of the node, which is assumed to be in a `GridPane`. Your `GridPane` probably isn't contained in another `GridPane` (and even if it were, that wouldn't be the column/row index you want). You need to register the mouse listener with the nodes that are inside the `GridPane`, not the `GridPane` itself.

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125571, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095954, or many others

Comment: You can use this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320110/javafx-how-to-get-column-and-row-index-in-gridpane

Comment: Awwww ok. I have understand the logic, but I do lots of confusion. I have edited my post to show you my file FXML, thank you :)